# Angular download pdf

Tags: angularjs, pdf, download, blob

I have angular function which get pdf data from server:

```
    printDocument: function (bundleId, policyId) {
        var fileName = "test.pdf";
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";

        $resource(baseUrlPrint, {
            bundleId: bundleId,
            policyId: policyId
        }, {
            get: {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            responseType:'arraybuffer',
            cache: true
        }).get().$promise.then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            var file = new Blob([result], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
            a.href = fileURL;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
        });
    }
```

When I check a *result* variable I see there is byte array contains pdf file. But when I open this file in Notepad++ I see that there is no pdf byte data but only:
*[object Object]*. Is something wrong with my Blob object?

Answer (score 0):

In case the API Rest retrieves an array of bytes you can simply use this js function

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('fileUtils')
        .service('DownloadService', DownloadService);

    DownloadService.$inject = ['$window'];

    function DownloadService($window) { // jshint ignore:line

        this.download = function (fileBytes, name, type) {
            var fileName = '';
            if (name) {
                 fileName = name + '.' + type;
            } else {
                 fileName = 'download.' + type;
            }

            var byteCharacters = atob(fileBytes);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/' + type });

            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, fileName);
            } else {
                //trick to download store a file having its URL
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = fileURL;
                a.target = '_blank';
                a.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        };
    }
})();
```